# How to pass a class between two modules?

Tags: system-verilog

I have two modules and a class and I would like to move that class from one module to the other. Something like this:

```
class foo;
   int x;
   int y;
endclass

module mod_A(output foo foo_inst, output event trig);
   initial begin
      foo my_foo = new;
      my_foo.x = 1;
      my_foo.y = 2;
      foo_inst = my_foo;
      ->trig;
   end
endmodule

module mod_B(input foo foo_inst, input event trig);
   always @(trig) begin
       $display("%d%d, is a funky number.", foo_inst.x, foo_inst.y);
   end
endmodule

module top();
   event trig;
   foo   foo_inst;
   mod_A mod_A(.trig, .foo_inst);
   mod_B mod_B(.trig, .foo_inst);
endmodule
```

Of course there're also some functions defined in the class which are used in each module.
The issue with this setup is that I'm seeing errors for each ports of mod_B:

```
Error-[RIPLIP] Register in low conn of input port
Non-net variable 'foo_inst' cannot be an input or inout port.
Non-net variable   'trig'   cannot be an input or inout port.
```

EDAplayground does not support class objects as module ports and [1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) only mentions interface declarations, events, arrays structures or unions in Port declarations (23.2.2) so my questions are:

- Is it even legal to pass classes through ports? If not, what is an elegant
  method of accomplishing this?
- What does "Register in low conn of
  input port" mean? I'm aware that this might be a compiler specific
  error and nothing indicative but if I knew what it was trying to tell me I might be a step closer to fixing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable of any type can be an `input` or `output` port. You might have to write for your compiler

```
input var foo foo_inst,
```

But it would be better to use a `ref` when a port is really a handle.

```
module mod_A(ref foo foo_inst, ref event trig);
```

Note that you have a typo with `foo_o` or `foo_inst` and a race condition between a trigger -`>trig`  and an event control `@(trig)`.

Comment: Hey @Dave, thanks for clearing that up. I knew SV supported passing by reference but I didn't think to apply it here. I've corrected the typo since that wasn't part of the problematic code.

Could you elaborate a little on the race condition? I've made a [small mockup on EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/8TW) and it seems to be working as intended.

Comment: You fixed the race condition by delaying the trigger. In your original example, you had the trigger from an `initial` block at time 0, and an `always @(event)` that also starts at time 0. Most simulators will start always block processes before initial block process, but you should not count on it.

Comment: The idea was almost there. Dynamically allocated objects **can only** be passed via reference. At least with the compiler I'm using - don't feel confident enough to speak for all of SV. Changing the input and outputs to 'ref' fixed the issue.

Without the delay the entire thing really does fall apart. I will address this in my modules. Thanks for pointing it out.